# What does "low birth" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "low birth" mean? quote

> His mother, Helena, was a Greek and a Christian, and of low birth.

(source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constantine_the_Great )

Comment: It's the [less common antonym of **high birth**.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=she+is+of+high+birth%2Cshe+is+of+low+birth&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=20) But both are very dated / snobbish terms today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will find the adjective ***lowborn*** in dictionaries, which will help you understand the expression ***of low birth***:

> born in a low condition or rank ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lowborn))

> born to a family that has a low social status ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=lowborn%20meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsaQdNviuUzrn6Q6xPUAwBH86oEKYQ%3A1662319602266&ei=8vsUY5fxD9mQ8gL__o0I&oq=lowborn&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIKCAAQgAQQhwIQFDIFCC4QgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCC4QgAQyCggAEIAEEIcCEBQyBQgAEIAEMgsILhCABBDHARCvATIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEOgQIIxAnOgUIABCRAjoLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6CwguEIAEELEDEIMBOgQIABBDOgcIABCxAxAKOgoIABCxAxCDARAKSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUABY9BRgkyFoAHABeACAAZEBiAGlBZIBAzUuMpgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz))

As nowadays, aristocracy in the technical sense has become rare, this term has lost frequency in use.

Answer (score 4):

[Lowborn](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lowborn) means "of humble birth," as opposed to being born with rank (i.e., [highborn](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/highborn)). As such, it's often used to describe someone as a [commoner](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/commoner), as in not being born a peer, aristocrat, noble, or royal.